# Ruby on Rails finding last saved record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a scenario I am finding the last saved record using the code

```
last = Category.find(:last)
```

This is to assign the id of category as the parent id to the sub-categories.

And so, I am assigning the it in this manner.

```
@subcategory.parent_id = last.id
```

This works fine, but when multiple users are trying to create Categories, then there is a wrong assignment of parent_id to the subcategory. (Sometimes it takes the id of a different category if that was created last.)

Is there any other way to find the last record?

Comment: This question needs to be fleshed out a bit. It's a good question but it's not clear why you are looking for the last category rather than using a known category you added (you added it, so you probably know what it is, right)? How would you like this system to behave and how have you implemented this behavior? I only ask these questions because I blundered off to write some answer only to discover that there were too many questions in my mind with respect to what you are trying to accomplish. Category.all.last.subcategories.create seems too easy an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a separate database query, you should be making changes at the same time.

If it is not possible to find the category you want by more specific means, i.e `last = Category.find_by_name('category I actually want')`, then update both your `Category` and the relevant `Subcategories` in the same place (your controller or model, however you've got it set up).

Answer (score 0):

Try this example...it might help you:

```
<% Specimen.find(:all, :order => 'distribution_sheet_id DESC', :limit => 10).each do |df| %>
  <%= df.id %>
<% end %>
```